flutter app not opening while running in debug or without debug mode. But its working fine when using the terminal code flutter run
The app was working fine . But once i tried to debug the app the app is not loading. its building , but only the flutter logo is been shown and then the options for restart, reload, etc.. closing automatically.
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G781B in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterLocationService(28092): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(28092): Binding to location service.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:53015/z1yvvI5mG_E=/ws
D/ProfileInstaller(28092): Installing profile for com.example.trim_spot_barber_side
this is the last thing that was shown in the terminal.
But when i perform it using terminal code flutter run, everything works fine
I need my app to perform as same as the way it works in flutter run code in debug mode also

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
